# How to add files from file input into array in Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, vuejs3

(I'm using vue 3)
I'm adding files from input file to array, then I conditionally render these file names. All working good on Chrome. Problem is when using Mozilla Firefox. In this browser array of files is overrided by last added file, for example:

1. add file-1 || output: file-1
2. add file-1 and next file-2 || output: file-1 file-1 (duplication).

There you can view and test this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-poitras-exux2z?file=/src/App.vue
method:

```
methods: {
addFile (file) {
  this.form.files.push(file);
}}
```

data structure:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        files: [],
      }};},
```

output:

```
<div>
<input @input="addFile($event.target.files)" type="file" name="" id="">
<p  v-for="file in form.files" :key="file">
            {{ file[0].name }}
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: none of the code you presented should work differently in firefox compared to other browsers - and in fact the code in the codesandbox works identically in all browsers

Comment: @JaromandaX thats not true. Check it first. You will see different output, depends it's firefox, or not.

Comment: `Check it first` - erm, I DID - and the page looks IDENTICAL for all browsers

Comment: my apologies .. firefox 104 works fine ... seems 103 does not!!! Well, that IS bizarre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a fix for you

```
methods: {
    addFile(file) {
        this.form.files.push({ ...file });
    }
}
```

Reason is - well, my theory is that `$event.target.files` is not a new object every time `addFile($event.target.files)` is called

You'll see this if you change your code to

```
methods: {
    addFile(file) {
        if (this.form.files.length) {
            console.log(this.form.files[0] === file)
        }
        this.form.files.push(file);
    }
}
```

This logs true in Firefox 103, but false in Firefox 104 (dev version)

Another alternative

```
<p v-for="file in form.files" :key="file">
  {{ file.name }}
</p>

methods: {
  addFile(file) {
    this.form.files.push(file[0]);
  },
}
```